# Dendrogram Label Overlapping

Tags: python, plot, label, dendrogram

I have a 2D array of relation data with labels(first row and column).

when I created the dendrogram, my Labels overlapped.
How can I make the labels separate evenly?

[image]

```
file= open(fileName)
line = file.readline()
file.close()
populations=line.split('\t')
del populations[0]


data = np.loadtxt(fileName, delimiter="\t",skiprows=1,usecols=range(1,len(populations)+1 ))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

Y1 = sch.linkage(data, method='ward',optimal_ordering=True)

Z1 = sch.dendrogram(Y1, orientation='top')

ind1= Z1['leaves']
arr = np.array(populations)
populations = arr[ind1]
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(populations)))
ax.set_xticklabels(populations )
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be easier to simply specify the labels in construction of the dendrogram, since they are known at the time of construction, something like the following

```
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch
import numpy as np           # Only needed for random sample data

np.random.seed(1)            # Seeded for reproducing

populations = np.arange(10)  # Create some random sample data
data = abs(np.random.randn(10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

Y1 = sch.linkage(data, method='ward',optimal_ordering=True)
Z1 = sch.dendrogram(Y1, orientation='top', labels=populations)

plt.show()
```

Would give you

[image]